# How can I combine sed commands to a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I Have to Operate the following sed commands over a file to remove some lines in that file. How can I make this a shell scipt with the file name as a variable. Or is there any simple way to do this as a shell script

```
sed -i '/^Total/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^CBSE/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^Keyword wise/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^wise/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^Select A/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^Enter A/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^(Keyword/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^State Name/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^SNo/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^Disclaimer/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^provided/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^at$/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^Designed/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^National/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^$/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^\t$/d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i '/^\s$/d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^         /d' delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^    /d' delhi222517.txt 
sed -i 's/^\([0-9]\)/--\1/g' delhi222517.txt
```

Comment: shell scripts are just shell commands in a text file, with an optional shebang (`#!...`) as the first line. The shebang's not necessary if you don't plant to invoke the script directly. eg `sh file.sh` v.s. `./file.sh`

Comment: I have to process this commands (some more addup...) between nearly 14000 files. So if I got a shell script with the file as a variable then that is very helpfull to me.

Answer (score 4):

The variable thing is easy:

```
F=delhi222517.txt
sed -i '/^Total/d' "$F"
...
```

Or if you want to pass the name of the file as argument to your script:

```
F="$1"
sed -i '/^Total/d' "$F"
...
```

But it is better to use the `sed` options to call it only once. You can use:

```
sed -i \
    -e '/^Total/d' \
    -e '/^CBSE/d' \
    -e '/^Keyword wise/d' \
    ...  \
    delhi222517.txt
```

Or you can write a file with the full script:

```
sed -i -f script.sed delhi222517.txt
```

Or if you feel geek enough, you can use the standard input:

```
sed -i -f - delhi222517.txt << EOF
/^Total/d
/^CBSE/d
/^Keyword wise/d
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

### On the Command Line

On the command line, you can separate sed commands with semi-colons or with multiple expression arguments. As generic examples:

```
# Using Semi-Colons
sed -i 's/foo/bar/; s/baz/quux/' infile

# Using Multiple Expressions
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/baz/quux/' infile
```

### Write a Full-Fledged Sed Script

In general, though, if your commands are numerous, stop using one-liners and build a full-fledged sed script. For example, you could create a file named `/tmp/foo.sed` containing the following commands from your question:

```
/^Total/d 
/^CBSE/d 
/^Keyword wise/d
/^wise/d
/^Select A/d
/^Enter A/d
/^(Keyword/d
/^State Name/d
/^SNo/d
/^Disclaimer/d
/^provided/d
/^at$/d
/^Designed/d
/^National/d
/^$/d
/^\t$/d
/^\s$/d
/^         /d
/^    /d
s/^\([0-9]\)/--\1/g
```

Then invoke your commands all at once. For example, using GNU sed:

```
infile='delhi222517.txt'
script='/tmp/foo.sed'
sed --in-place --file="$script" "$infile"
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can put them in a a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some sanity checks
file="$1"

sed -i '/^Total/d' "$file"
sed -i '/^CBSE/d' "$file"
sed -i '/^Keyword wise/d' "$file"
sed -i '/^wise/d' "$file"
#.. more sed commands
```

btw your various sed commands can be combined into 1 or fewer sed command using reges like:

```
sed -r -i '/^(Total|CBSE)/d' "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do all in go:

```
file=delhi222517.txt
awk '!/^(Total|CBSE|Keyword wise|wise)/' "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your script is not going to run any program other than sed your file, then this may be the cleanest way to set it up:

```
#!/bin/sed -f     # <- run the file passed to the program from the command-line
/^Total/Id        # /I is the case-insensitive flag, replacing sed -i
/^CBSE/Id
/^Keyword wise/Id
/^wise/Id
/^Select A/Id
/^Enter A/Id
...
```

Make the above script executable, and then just pass it the filename that you wish to convert:
./mysedscript delhi222517.txt